# Bar graph not taking 100%

Tags: chart.js

I have a problem when generating a bar chart :

[image]

I don't understand why 50%+50% doesn't smoke 100% of the seat? Config seems to be good ? Did i miss something?

Here the code :

```
new Chart(draw, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [currentYear],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Legend 1',
          data: [50],
          backgroundColor: '#fdfd96', // yellow
        },
        {
          label: 'Legend 2',
          data: [50],
          backgroundColor: '#77b5fe', // blue
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true,
        },
      },
      animation: {
        onComplete: function () {
          saveChartAsImage(
            this.toBase64Image(),
            currentYear,
            companyId,
            'actif',
            manualMode,
          );
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and configuration looks correct and works *( demo seen below )* ***but*** if you want to be on the save side yo can add the properties `max:100` to the `y` axis, this could fix the hight issue.

**Here the demo:**

```js
const data = {
    labels: [2022],
    datasets: [{
          label: 'Legend 1',
          data: [50],
          backgroundColor: '#fdfd96', // yellow
        },
        {
          label: 'Legend 2',
          data: [50],
          backgroundColor: '#77b5fe', // blue
        },],
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: {
            onComplete: function () {
                let img = document.createElement('img')
                let url = this.toBase64Image()
                img.src = url
                document.querySelector('#imagePreview').append(img);
            }
        },
        scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true,
          max:100
        },
    }}
};

var cart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
<b> preview Image </b>
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

**Update screenshot of result:**

[image: screenshot from snippet result]

**Update:**

*After testing the assumtion must be, that the save function is defective or there is some sort of race condition with a different chart. Since createing a image `onComplete` creates a correct images, in the updated demo.*

I'm assuming the wrong visuals have to to with the animation, not being finished when the image is created, if this is so, one could workaround this fact *(or just to test the theory)*, with using a timeout for creating the image, something like this

```
onComplete: function () {
    setTimeout( () => {
        saveChartAsImage(
            this.toBase64Image(),
            currentYear,
            companyId,
            'actif',
            manualMode,
         );
    }, 1000); // <-- One Second should be enough for the animation to end
}
```

Comment: I have the same result :/ I don't know what to do ! Thanks for your help

Comment: @aksl95 if you run the code snippet you don't see thesame result as the added image?

Comment: Yes, I see like you. But it's the generation of the image that has a problem

Comment: @aksl95 the problem must be in the `saveChartAsImage` , because I updated my answer to add a preview image on the evnet `onComplete`, and it is display correct. _(or are you by any chance creating two chart on the same page, this might interferre )_

Comment: @aksl95 btw.: a possible ***quick & dirty***  workaround could be to use `setTimeout` in the `onComplete` event function. I asume the wrong size is shown becaus the animation didn't finish.

Comment: @aksl95 I just wanted to ask did the `setTimeout` workaround work, or did you maybe found a better solution?